# How to receive json return message in saga try catch when it fails?

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

I have saga try catch for axios request. However, catch(err) returns message just like

```
Error: Request failed with status code 400
```

I want to display the error message from the server which is sent by res.state(400).json(errors). On Dev console -> Network, I clearly see my JSON file has returned.

How can I access the returned JSON inside of catch(err) block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch errors in axios using `catch` (block or function - depends if you use `try/catch` or Promise API). You can access the failing response data using [`error.response`](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors).

Below is an example of `useEffect` hook fetching the data from an endpoint and handling the error.

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://your-domain/error")
      .then((response) => console.log("Response", response.body))
      .catch((error) =>
        console.log(`HTTP Status Code: ${error.response.status}; data: ${JSON.stringify(error.response.data)}`)
      );
  }, []);
```

The endpoint itself is simple Express endpoint defined as follows:

```js
app.get("/error", (req, res) => {
  console.log("error");
  res.status(404).json({ error: "Not found" });
});
```

It returns response with 404 status code and `{error: "Not found"}` body.